# How to get max length (in bytes) of a variable-length column?

Tags: postgresql

I want to get max length (in bytes) of a variable-length column. One of my columns has the following definition:

- `shortname character varying(35) NOT NULL`
- `userid integer NOT NULL`
- `columncount smallint NOT NULL`

I tried to retrieve some info from the `pg_attribute` table, but the `attlen` column has `-1` value for all variable-length columns. I also tried to use `pg_column_size` function, but it doesn't accept the name of the column as an input parameter.

It can be easily done in SQL Server.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Are there any other ways to get the value I'm looking for?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Are you talking about `character_maximum_length column` of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`? Unfortunately this column doesn't contain the number of bytes and it has `null` for the types like `timestamp`, `integer`, etc.

Comment: you can't see the maximum length in bytes because it depends on the actual characters stored in the column. A single character may take up to 4 bytes in a multi-byte encoding. So showing the maximum length in bytes doesn't make sense in `information_schema.columns`. So the absolute maximum length in bytes is "number of characters *  maximum length of a single character for the encoding being use". If you use UTF-8 you can just multiply the number of characters by 4

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, but do we have something similar to SQL Server? The `max_length` column of the `sys.columns` is able to display max length of fixed-size and variable-length columns.

Comment: As I said: if you use UTF-8, just use `character_maximum_length * 4 as max_length_in_bytes`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But it will work only for character types. Looks like I need to find some workaround for other types like `timestamp`, `integer`, `money`, etc. I think I can return a constants for fixed-size types.

Comment: The documentation thoroughly describes storage requirements for each type. Why do you need the documentation repeated in the output of a query? Why can’t you just RTFM?

Comment: @Bohemian I'm working on schema conversion and I have to convert SQL Server stored procedure. It has to be run on PostgreSQL. The procedure is complicated enough and we do something like that in `WHERE` statement `WHERE #tempTable.ColumnLength < sys.columns.max_length`.

Comment: See "[Migrate your mindset](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/)"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a CASE expression checks `pg_attribute.attlen` and then calculate the maximum size in bytes depending on that. To get the max size for a varchar column you can "steal" the expression used in `information_schema.columns.character_octet_length` for `varchar` or `char` columns

Something along the lines:

```
select a.attname, 
       t.typname,
       case 
          when a.attlen <> -1 then attlen
          when t.typname in ('bytea', 'text') then pg_size_bytes('1GB')
          when t.typname in ('varchar', 'char') then information_schema._pg_char_octet_length(information_schema._pg_truetypid(a.*, t.*), information_schema._pg_truetypmod(a.*, t.*))
       end as max_bytes
from pg_attribute a
  join pg_type t on a.atttypid = t.oid
where a.attrelid = 'stuff.test'::regclass
  and a.attnum > 0
  and not a.attisdropped;
```

Note that this won't return a proper size for `numeric` as that is also a variable length type. The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) says "*he actual storage requirement is two bytes for each group of four decimal digits, plus three to eight bytes overhead*".

---

As a side note: this seems an extremely strange thing to do. Especially with your mentioning of temp tables in stored procedures. More often than not, the use of temp tables is not needed in Postgres. Instead of blindly copying the old approach that might have worked well in SQL Server, you should understand how Postgres works and change the approach to match the best practices in Postgres.

I have seen many migrations fail or deliver mediocre performance because of the assumption that the best practices for "System A" can be applied without any change to "System B". You need to [migrate your mindset](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/) as well.

If this checks the columns of a temp table, then why not simply check the *actual* size of the column values using `pg_column_size()`?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I agree with you that converting the schema line by line might be a bad decision. I think I will need to re-implement the procedure based on PostgreSQL specific features.